# Snarkjs- Proof still validates for incorrect witness

Tags: zk-snark, circom

Very new to ZKsnarks. I'm trying to build a simple application to check whether the input number matches a certain predefined number or not.
I have followed all the steps mentioned in the [SnarkJs doc](https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs#readme).

Here is the circuit for my use case:

```
pragma circom 2.0.0;

template IsZero() {
    signal input in;
    signal output out;

    signal inv;

    inv <-- in!=0 ? 1/in : 0;

    out <== -in*inv +1;
    in*out === 0;
}
template verifier() {
    signal input a;
    signal output b;
    signal c <== 9429723347216097781814234269377894115729242880998740711935743712243189718113;
    
    component isz = IsZero();

    a - c ==> isz.in;

    isz.out ==> b;
}

component main = verifier();
```

However, when I try to verify an incorrect witness, the verifier contract still validates it.

This is what I'm doing:

First get the calldata params

```
proof = await snarkjs.plonk.fullProve( { a: 5}, "circuit_js/circuit.wasm", "circuit_final.zkey");
await snarkjs.plonk.exportSolidityCallData(proof["proof"], proof["publicSignals"]);
```

Then try to verify with verifier.sol contract. However it still validates it. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether `a` is matching the predefined `c`, you need to have a constraint for that specific check. So it's not enough to assign `a - c` to the output. You need to have the following constraint: `isz.out === 1`. Otherwise, `b` is merely an output. So `5 - 9429723347216097781814234269377894115729242880998740711935743712243189718113` is nonzero, however, there is no violation of any constraint. In fact, you were proving that `5 - 9429723347216097781814234269377894115729242880998740711935743712243189718113` is non-zero, and the circuit output was indeed `0` (false), which is correct. If you add the aforementioned constraint, you can remove the output signal altogether.